# Cannot login on Stack Overflow. Redirected -302- to join the community page

Tags: support, user-interface, users, login

I am trying to log in on Stack Overflow:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/login >>>(Redirect 302)>>>
https://stackoverflow.com/users/join?ssrc=login
```

In this second page there is **no chance to login**. Just a '**Join the community**' button.

Anyway I can login using 'private browsing'. But that is annoying.
I guess it is related with the page checking my current Google account.

```
Request URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302
Remote Address: 151.101.1.69:443
```

Comment: Can you include request and response headers (via developer tools for example), to see where the redirect is coming from? Also try clearing cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Solved just clearing cookies.

My mistake as I though  I was already clearing them using Chrome Dev Tools>application>Clear storage>clear site data.